# Блокировка клавиатуры

Tags: winapi, windows

Как блокировать клавиатуру? BlokInput не подходит, мышь блокироваться не должна!

Comment: Конечно же BlockInput

Answer (score 1):

ставим хук на кейбоард ... и не отдаём эти хуки дальше по цепочке ...

Comment: только _LL хук... чтоб уж точно

Answer (score 0):

[BlockInput function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646290.aspx)

```
BOOL WINAPI BlockInput(
  _In_ BOOL fBlockIt
);
```